# Angular ngFor with ngClass

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-class

I have an array with weather conditions and an arrray with icon class names with the same size as the weather conditions. I want to show the 'i' tag with the class name of the iconNames[i]. How can I do that?

```
<li *ngFor="let item of weather; let i = index">
  <h1>{{ item.valid_date }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ item.temp }}</h2>
  <i [ngClass]="{iconNames[i]}"></i>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried this, without  {{}} <i [ngClass]="iconNames[i]"></i>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) for that:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of weather; let i = index">
  <h1>{{ item.valid_date }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ item.temp }}</h2>
  <i [class]="iconNames[i]"></i>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `ngClass` you can create function in your component and call it inside `*ngFor` to get dynamic value

```
getClassName(i) {
    return iconNames[i];
}
```

Call in html

```
<li *ngFor="let item of weather; let i = index">
  <h1>{{ item.valid_date }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ item.temp }}</h2>
  <i [ngClass]="getClasses(i)"></i>
</li>
```